# Alternative to a global variable for passing objects between activities

Tags: android

I need to pass a list of objects between activities, I am using a public static global variable in my Application class.

The problem is that this variable seems to be the first to be destroyed when the activity goes in the background for a while.

I never have problems with the activity going in the background but whenever I use a global variable like this, it always the first gets garbage collected or something to fee memory. This causes my application to crash.

How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: You can pass the data to activity using a `bundle` with Intent

Comment: So much nonsense in the answers!  It is true that the correct way is to serialise the objects and pass them with the intent.  However, Android does NOT randomly GC variables.  It will never "reset", or whatever other word you want to use, a static variable in the `Application` singleton.  Quite simply, your app went to the background and is destroyed.  When you went back to the app, it is restarted so the variables are set to their initial values.  If you want to persist their values, store them and reload in `Application.onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad approach of doing it storing it in a global variable.
You should either serialize your class or create a Singleton pattern and store that object in it.

Serializable Approach

```
public class ClassIntanceOne implements Serializable{
}

//In Activity
ClassIntanceOne class_instance_one = new ClassIntanceOne();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();  
bundle.putSerializable("object1", class_instance_one);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(/*Your class*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to [include the objects in the intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)), that is starting the other activity. This requires, that your objects implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html).

Then just call:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("myobjects", listOfObjects);
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice in android to make use of globel static variables. The GC will always remove them when your activity goes to the background as the value is not used anymore. Also don't try to keep your object longer in memory as you need it. This may cause poor performance on devices with less memory.

Like SME_Dev said, you will need to serialzie your objects and pass them as an intent extra to the activitys.

When you can searialize your objects it's also easier to restore the current state of the app if it get's destroyed because you can make use of the [recreating mechanism](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) in android.

Comment: Excuse me, but nonsense.  A static variable in a POJO exists as long as any instance of it's containing class exists.  A static of the `Application` singleton has a life time equal to the app instance.  See my comment above.

Comment: Maybe my formulation was wrong. I agree that the variable exists as long as the app instance is available, but still does the GC collect classes that are not referenced anymore. In this case the list of objects get collected because the activity refering to it is gone. The variable is still there but contains null.

Comment: `In this case the list of objects get collected because the activity refering to it is gone. The variable is still there but contains null`  Nope.  Try it, it's really easy.  Create a static of the `Application` class.  Now set it's value in an `Activity`.  `finish()` that activity and start another one.  Now read the value.  If you keep the app in the foreground, the value of that static will persist for the life time of the app. It does not matter whether it's a primitive or a reference to an object, it will persist.  That's why it's so dangerous if not used carefully.

Comment: Put another way, there seems to be this urban myth that Java on Android somehow differs from every other memory managed, sweep and mark language.  It does not.  The exact same rules for object scope and life time apply.  A variable will never be GCed, regardless of any object it points to, if any instance of it's containing class exists.  Therefore, no variable will be GCed because it cannot exist if no references of the object it refers to exist.  `The GC will always remove them when your activity goes to the background as the value is not used anymore` - this is just plain wrong.

Comment: But the `Application` class will be unloaded if the app stays in background for some time -> get's GCed. Of course is the behaviour the same as with any other java but the possiblity is quite high that the Application get's destroyed because of longer inactive. Some devices even destroy the application as soon as they press the back button. Anyway bad practise, serialise it :-)

Comment: `But the Application class will be unloaded`. Again, no it won't.  The Application class is **never** GCed since the application context has a reference as long as the app is running.  You are assuming that because the Application instance no longer exists, it has been GCed.  In fact, the app process has been killed because Android needs more memory or has otherwise chosen to kill the app. This is normal behaviour and is not GC.  When you go back to the app, it is started up from scratch.